Performing a biometric verification process during the Azure B2C registration custom flow
During Azure B2C registration we would like to break out to custom web pages that will take a selfie of the user and a photo of an id document that will then be send to an API that will validate the user's identity.
The only way I can think of doing this is to "hijack" the registration link on the login page to redirect to a separate web app that will do the verification and if successful, will then create the user on Azure B2C using Graph API. My problem is how to then redirect back to Azure B2C with a status that the registration was successful.
I would appreciate any ideas on how to achieve the verification process and whether the way I described above is even feasible.

One way to do this would be to use a third-party provider that provides this service.
The interface is via API, which you can call with custom policies.
The third-party provider then provides the web page flow.
